# A question about a video (lecture on measures)

Tags: measure-theory

I watched a lecture: http://ppt.cc/D1iT (youtube.com)

Please see the part from `4:14`: while the professor says the set with 4 to be all of the ones 3, 4, 5.... a note jumps out on the screen saying this is wrong.

I am confused about this part. Why is it wrong to take $E_i = 4$ for $i > 3$ and 
does additivity hold for finite unions?

Comment: Yes, additivity holds for finite unions. Take $E_i=\varnothing$ for $i>n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amusing, but confusing! He is looking at a finite set $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$. So everything works fine. You can assign a prob $\frac{1}{n}$ to each of the singleton sets $\{1\},\{2\},\dots$ and extend that to the whole set. So any subset with $k$ elements just has prob $\frac{k}{n}$.

Unfortunately, he muddied the waters by saying "up to infinity" just after 4:25. Then a note popped up confusing things still further. Just ignore all that.

Yes, additivity is fine for finite unions.

[The confusing part, which is why the video is such a gem, is that additivity is also fine for countably infinite unions, so the correction confused matters further.]